# How do i find the rolling correlation over last 10 periods for different countries within a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to find the rolling correlation between Mean BMI and Purchasing power parity so for every country I get the correlation printed in a separate column in 2016

[image: Data Frame head]

i tried using a loop but after finding the first instance where df['Year]==2016 it just continued on finding the rolling average regardless of year.

```
for i in range (len(df)):
if df['Year'][i]==2016:
    df['corr']=df['Purchasing power parity'].rolling(11).corr(df['Mean BMI'])
```

this is the new df after the code was run
[image: after code was run]

Comment: What exactly did you try?

Comment: hey chris I'll edit the question to show what i have tried. thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Pandas built in rolling correlation function...
For each function, you can basically do a simple group by and iterate through each group and get the result.

For each country you can have something like this...

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import random


>>> data = pd.DataFrame([[i, i+random.randint(-99,99)] for i in range(100)], columns=[['Mean BMI', 'Purchase Power Parity']])
   Mean BMI Purchase Power Parity
0         0                    20
1         1                   -34
2         2                    93
3         3                    33
4         4                   -43
..      ...                   ...
95       95                   190
96       96                    19
97       97                    83
98       98                    49
99       99                   187


>>> data.rolling(4).corr(pairwise=False)

   Mean BMI Purchase Power Parity
0       NaN                   NaN
1       NaN                   NaN
2       NaN                   NaN
3       1.0                   1.0
4       1.0                   1.0
..      ...                   ...
95      1.0                   1.0
96      1.0                   1.0
97      1.0                   1.0
98      1.0                   1.0
99      1.0                   1.0
```